# Can you modify a rough opening by 1 inch

Tags: doors

The original door for my exterior entryway measures 60.5 inches. The door was measured for a new door by a lumber company and they ordered the door. After the door arrived, it measured 61.5 inches, the same size as my rough opening. What should I do? Can the rough opening be adjusted in someway to allow the necessary opening around the door for contraction and expansion over time.

Comment: We have no idea how the current opening is framed (or even what _material_ we're talking about). Please revise to add enough information for us to help. Also critical is whether this is a load-bearing wall.

Comment: The correct action is to send the wrong sized door back and get a correctly sized door instead.  Modifying the rough opening is not trivial and the supplier's screw-up is not a good reason to do it.

Comment: It can be with some work, but the person who ordered the wrong size door should reorder the right size.  It is their problem, not yours.

Answer (score 2):

It's far easier to modify the door than the opening. Whacking an inch or so off oversize doors is routine practice in the door installation biz. Your "lumber company" may even be equipped to do that, I'd suggest asking them. They might even do it at no charge if it can be determined they are responsible for sending the wrong size.

Comment: As a mention, the modification of the door as it is right now, may not be practical, since door may already be drilled for the knob. The material on the edges of todays doors are about 1" thick, to remove 1" off of one side will have screws going into the core of the door, in many cases is not substantial enough to hold screws. To remove a 1/2" off of both would need to be done before the door is prepped for the knob and deadbolt.